# SQL, Laravel score/rank results using selectRaw and LIKE?

Tags: sql, laravel, ranking

This works for a single name...

```
Result::whereIn('id', $log->result_ids)
      ->select('*')
      ->selectRaw("(owner LIKE ? ) + 
                   (owner LIKE ? ) + 
                   (city LIKE ? ) AS score", 
                   ['%CHARLOTTE%', '%RICHARD%', 'Salem'])
      ->get();
```

But I want to dynamically use an array of owners, cities and so on...

```
$owners = [ 
     'CHARLOTTE', 
     'RICHARD'
     // ... or more 
];
$cities = [ 
     'SALEM', 
     'PORTLAND'
     // ... or more 
];

Result::whereIn('id', $log->result_ids)
      ->select('*')
      ->selectRaw("(owner LIKE ? ) + 
                   (city LIKE ? ) AS score", 
                   [$owners, $cities])
      ->get();
```

@Mehmet Bütün, here is my modified version of your answer, it does work. Is there a cleaner way?

```
$spouses = ['Patricia', 'Cindy'];
$cities  = ['Riverside', 'San Diego'];

$string_to_spouse_score = collect($spouses)->map( function($spouse) {
      return "(owner LIKE '%".strtoupper($spouse)."%' )";
})->join(' + ') . " as spouse_score";

$cities_string = collect($cities)->map( function($city) {
      return strtoupper($city);
})->join(' OR city LIKE ');

Result::whereIn('id', $result_ids)->select('*')
      ->selectRaw("(owner LIKE ? ) as owner_score", ['%'.strtoupper($owner->first_name).'%'])
      ->selectRaw($string_to_spouse_score) // as spouse_score
      ->selectRaw("(city LIKE ? ) as city_score", [$cities_string])
      ->selectRaw("(SELECT(owner_score)) + (SELECT(spouse_score)) + (SELECT(city_score)) as score")
      ->having('score', '>', 0)
      ->orderBy('score', 'desc')
      ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use `array` instead of `string`. Try this (I hope it will work):

```
$owners = [ 
     'CHARLOTTE', 
     'RICHARD'
     // ... or more 
];
$cities = [ 
     'SALEM', 
     'PORTLAND'
     // ... or more 
];


$new_owners=array();
foreach ($owners as $owner){
    $new_owners[]='%'.$owner.'%';
}
$owners_query_string= implode(' OR owner LIKE ', $new_owners);


$new_cities=array();
foreach ($cities as $city){
    $new_cities[]='%'.$city.'%';
}
$cities_query_string= implode(' OR city LIKE ', $new_cities);

Result::whereIn('id', $log->result_ids)
      ->select('*')
      ->selectRaw("(owner LIKE ? ) + 
                   (city LIKE ? ) AS score", 
                   [$owners_query_string, $cities_query_string])
      ->get();
```

Comment: almost works... it doesn't score multiple matches. If multiple owners match it only counts one this way.

Comment: The code you wrote above was like this. Can you explain exactly what you want to do?

Comment: I'm scoring results based on owner and city matches... if I knew how to write it I wouldn't have asked the question ;) if there are multiple owners matched the score should reflect that rather than scoring 1. 

I tried rewriting the solution based on your answer that scores multiples. I came up with a version that works but it seems anything but elegant. I'll post it above... what do you think?

Comment: @Robert You have a complex query. I've reviewed the code you shared, but I must say there are still sections that I don't understand (for ex: `$obit->first_name`). You can write SQL code directly. But I think "if it works don't touch it" :)